# Necesito evitar la division entre 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

al ejecutar este código en la penúltima línea me salta el error de division by cero y no se cómo evitarlo.Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho,muchas gracias(el error está en 1/hist[index] por si acaso)

```
def trSample(ps,img):
    res,hist=[(0,0,0)]*len(ps),[0]*len(ps)
    width,height=img.size
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            index=minIndex((img.getpixel((x,y))),ps)
            res[index]=add(res[index],img.getpixel((x,y)))
            hist[index]+=1
    for index in range(len(ps)):
        res[index]=mul(res[index],1/hist[index])
    return res
```

Comment: Puedes separar la operación `1/hist[index]` en una variable y, antes de hacerla, comprobar que `his[index]` sea distinto de 0. Si es distinto de 0, haces la división. Si es igual a 0, sustituyes todo el resultado por el valor que sea necesario (supongo que 0), en vez de hacer la operación.

Comment: ¿Así?
    for index in range(len(ps)):
        if (hist[index])!=0:
            res[index]=mul(res[index],1/hist[index])
        else:
            res[index]=mul(res[index],0)
    return res

Comment: También puedes usar una excepción, revisa la sección 9.6 de este enlace: http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/errors.html
En él te dan un ejemplo de división por cero

Comment: @JuanMartinez esa es una solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar la forma indeterminada (`0/0`) o en este caso el infinito (`1/0`) sugiero usar el operador lógico `or` en el denominador:

```
1/(hist[index] or 1)  # se imprime 1 cuando hist[index]=0
```

Por qué funciona lo anterior, observese lo siguiente:

```
print(0 or 1) # Python imprime 1 (Interes en este caso)
print(3 or 1) # Python imprime 3 (Interes en este caso)
print(0 or 2) # Python imprime 2

print(0 and 1) # Python imprime 0
print(0 and 2) # Python imprime 0
print(0 and 0) # Python imprime 0

print(3 and 0) # Python imprime 0
print(3 and 1) # Python imprime 1
print(3 and 2) # Python imprime 2
```

> Es decir, el operador `or` es equivalente a una función que determina el **máximo** entre dos números `max(0,1)=1`, mientras que el operador `and` es lo contrario, su comportamiento es equivalente a una función que determina el **mínimo** entre dos números `min(3,1)=1`.

Esto además permite construir funciones anómimas, digamos promediar los elementos de una lista, la cual puede ser  `[]`.

```
promedioLista = lambda x: sum(x)/(len(x) or 1)
```

Y aclarando de nuevo `1/0` es infinito, su reemplazo puedo ser `0` o `1` (o cualquier otro valor) de acuerdo a vuestras necesidades, propuse el `1` porque me parece que se simplifica código.

Comment: Muchas gracias,a ver si funciona.