# Cómo saber cuantas veces se repite un número en una tabla en Python sin usar .count

Tags: python, condiciones, random

Creé una `tabla` con una dimensión determinada, que relleno de forma aleatoria, y quiero saber las veces que se repiten los números que contiene dicha `tabla`.

He probado usar `.count()`, pero no me deja, y no sé muy bien cómo solucionarlo.

Otra opción que se me ocurrió, es pasar la `tabla` a un vector, es decir, pasar de tener un objeto del tipo `tabla=([...])` a uno del tipo `tabla=[...]` , donde si deja usar `.count()`, pero tampoco sé como podría convertir un objeto en el otro.

Es imprescindible que la lista de números este al principio como un objeto del tipo `tabla=([...])`, puesto que esta lista forma parte de un programa más complejo que no he adjuntado porque funciona bien, solamente se traba en este paso.

Adjunto el código:

```
from numpy import zeros, log, linspace, arange
from random import random, seed

m=4
tabla=zeros(m,float)

for i in range(m):
    if random()>0.5:
        tabla[i]=1
    else:
        tabla[i]=3 

print(tabla) 

print(tabla.count(2))
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se bien si es lo que buscas, pero guiándome de

> "y quiero saber las veces que se repiten los números que contiene
>   dicha tabla"

una forma rápida de contar los elementos de una lista, puede ser con el módulo [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections)

```
>>> import collections
>>> list1 = [1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
>>> collections.Counter(list1)
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```

El resultado es un iterador, por lo que puedes agregarlo a una estructura de control (python 3.x)

```
cuenta = collections.Counter(list1)
for key, value in cuenta.items():
    print('{} se repite {} veces'.format(key, value))
```

resultado:

```
1 se repite 3 veces
3 se repite 1 veces
2 se repite 2 veces
```

En caso de python 2, usar

```
for key, value in cuenta.iteritems():
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Creo que primero hay que comprender que hace `if... : else: ...` dentro del bucle `for`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia sólo son generados dos números discretos `1` y `3` en función al valor de `random()`

En tal sentido cuando se emplea en la sentencia:

```
print(tabla.count(2))
```

Siempre se imprime cero (`0`) porque el número dos (`2`) nunca es creado, por tanto, lo correcto sería aplicar lo siguiente para lo publicado:

```
 print(tabla.count(1)) # el total de números 1 en tabla
 print(tabla.count(3)) # el total de números 3 en tabla
```

Como ya comentaron en una respuesta previa se puede usar `import collections` y aplicar directamente lo siguiente:

```
print(collections.Counter(tabla))
# Se imprime: Counter({1: 2, 3: 2}) 
# lo cual cambia porque son números aleatorios
```

Adicionalmente me gustaría indicar que la estructura `if... : else: ...` es similar a:

```
tabla[i] = random()>0.5 and 1 or 3
```

Es decir para los dos casos que tiene la sentencia `if`

```
print (True and 1 or 3)  # Se imprime 1
print (False and 1 or 3) # Se imprime 3
```

Este comportamiento ya lo expliqué en:

- [Necesito evitar la division entre 0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247945/necesito-evitar-la-division-entre-0/247955#247955)
- [Reescribir un simple juego sin usar la sentencia “goto”](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6168/reescribir-un-simple-juego-sin-usar-la-sentencia-goto/170903#170903)

Este ultimo si bien es **Lua** la sintaxis es exactamente igual a **Python** lo único que si tendría que acotar es que la función anónima luego de `import math` quedaría

```
cal = lambda x: x!=0 and math.sin(x)/x or 1
```

Lo cual como acoté aquella vez es parecido a **C#** con su [operador ?:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: De acuerdo,ahora me queda mucho más claro. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda !